# Insert image before WordPress comments

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have limited experience with JavaScript and I am wanting to insert three columns of images before the comments module on all WordPress posts. Would I create an image element using:

```
let sponsorImage = document.createElement('img');
```

If so, how would I then inject this image immediately before the WordPress comments module? The comments module has a class name of `el-post-meta-wrapper-bottom` but I do not understand how to create three columns or inject them before this element.

[Here](http://1320video.flywheelsites.com/test-post/) is a test post I spun. Any help or direction is much appreciated.

Comment: Can't you edit the PHP/HTML template instead?

Comment: I'm sure that's super viable. I have no php experience.

Comment: @AndrewTuzson you wanna just add static img or it's dynamic ?

Comment: Just static images that can link out to other sites.

Answer (score 0):

It'd be much easier to add these in the HTML template than to insert them with JS, unless there's some other requirement we don't know about. Look in your site's `wp-content/themes/<your theme>` folder and you will find that `.el-post-meta-wrapper-bottom` element and can add in some boring old HTML.

Comment: That makes sense. There are no other requirements that I haven't shared. Just need three columns that I can place images in.